# typescript error: Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' - in accessing specific key in array

Tags: typescript

I've got this piece of code (TypeScript). Now there's a TS error for item[0]:
Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
What should I do? thanks.

```
  const myFunc = (parentId: string, results = []) => {
    const item = inventoryData.filter(({ id }: Item) => id === parentId);
    results.push(item[0]);
    return results;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript when you declare a variable and assign it with [] the type is implicitly taken as `never`.

so you can modify `results = []` to `results:any[] = []`

```
  const myFunc = (parentId: string, results:any[] = []) => {
    const item = inventoryData.filter(({ id }: Item) => id === parentId);
    results.push(item[0]);
    return results;
  };
```

hope this help.